# How to correctly use [VertexSE3Expmap] as two connecting Vertex in Edge_V_V_GICP?

Tags: slam, c++

I am working on a pose estimation problem solved by Levenberg-Marquardt with [g2o](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o).

I want to build 3D rigid constraint between two pose, so I choose **Edge_V_V_GICP** and test the [g2o/examples/icp/gicp_demo.cpp](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/g2o/examples/icp/gicp_demo.cpp) .

I changed the Vertex class of  **Edge_V_V_GICP**  from VertexSE3 to **VertexSE3Expmap**, meanwhile I rewrite some code to make original  **Edge_V_V_GICP**  compatible with VertexSE3Expmap. Run gicp_demo.cpp, the Optimization failed early ( it should iterate 10 times )...

```
amax:~/Project/g2o/bin$ ./gicp_demo 
0 0 0 | 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 | 0 0 0 1
[VertexSE3Expmap] GICPEdge
Initial Second vertex =   0   0 0.2
Initial chi2 = 7.885232
iteration= 0     chi2= 7.885232  time= 0.00560661    cumTime= 0.00560661     edges= 1000     schur= 0    lambda= 135142887383192720.000000   levenbergIter= 10
Iteration = 10

Second vertex should be near 0,0,1
0 0 0
  0   0 0.2
Final chi2 = 7.885232
```

Because using original vertex Class: VertexSE3 lead to successful optimization, I guess something wrong with VertexSE3Expmap...

Here are involved codes which I changed to make original  **Edge_V_V_GICP**  compatible with VertexSE3Expmap:
[gicp_demo.cpp](https://github.com/LongruiDong/For_debug/blob/master/g2o/examples/icp/gicp_demo.cpp), [types_icp.h](https://github.com/LongruiDong/For_debug/blob/master/g2o/types/icp/types_icp.h), [types_icp.cpp](https://github.com/LongruiDong/For_debug/blob/master/g2o/types/icp/types_icp.cpp)

I have been confused by this question for days,
Anybody know how to fix this? How to correctly use [VertexSE3Expmap] as two connecting Vertex in Edge_V_V_GICP ?

I have also made an issue in [g2o github](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/issues/433)...

Thanks in advance!!